# Forbidden Error When JSON From A File Imported Using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-app-configuration

I am trying to import contents of a JSON file using Azure CLI and I am continuously getting forbidden error as shown in the snapshot given below.  Any pointers / suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

I used the command given below.  The command is straight forward and shown in the code snippet given below.

```
az appconfig kv import -s file --format json --path "./settings.json"
    --content-type "application/json"
    --separator :
    --depth 2 
    --connection-string "{app-config-connection-string}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time, I found something.
If a **read-only** connection string is used, then you will get the "forbidden" error as shown in the snapshot in the question.

We need to use **read-write** connection string and then, it should work as expected.

```
az appconfig kv import -s file --format json --path "./settings.json"
    --content-type "application/json"
    --separator :
    --depth 2 
    --connection-string "{app-config-read-write-connection-string}"
```

If you are using `--name` instead of `--connection-string` switch, then make sure that you have appropriate permissions for writing to the Azure App Configuration store.